# The bottom of the first page of a report

Tags: sourcecode

I want to obtain the bottom of my first page of my report like the following

[image]

> Could you please help me with the necessary codes?

My attempt:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
   \usepackage[francais]{babel}
   %-----accent                     
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %-----
   \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pifont}
  \usepackage{framed}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
   \usepackage{palatino}
   %---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing
  %--------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
 %----------------------------------------------
 \begin{document}
      %----------------------------------------------
     \begin{figure}[h]
       \begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{\;\;\;\;Republic of...}\\ 
  \textbf{Ministry of Higher Education, Scientific Research
  and Information and Communication Technologies}\\
   \textbf{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;... University}\\
  \textbf{National Engineering School of ... }
   \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
   \begin{minipage}[h]{.5\linewidth}
  \vskip 0.1 cm \hskip 4 cm
 \includegraphics[width=4cm]{picture}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
%----------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though, it is tagged under `sourcecode` could you atleast show us how far you have tried? may be (usually always) we could help you from there.

Comment: @Raaja Please see my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights:

1. Use `[b]` option on figure; add a `\mbox{}` on otherwise blank page so that float doesn't become a `[p]` float.
2. Use `\Longstack`s for the text
3. Use `\rlap` of left-most stack and `\llap` of right-most stack, so that the figure remains centered.
4. Use `\hfill` to balance gaps left and right of image.
5. Use `figure*` so that you don't expend a figure number.
6. Use full-width stacked `\rule`s to get the color bars at the bottom.
7. `\scriptsize` to make it all fit.
8. `\bfseries` once rather than many, many `\textbf`s.

The MWE:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
   \usepackage[francais]{babel}
   %-----accent                     
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %-----
   \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pifont}
  \usepackage{framed}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
   \usepackage{palatino}
   %---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing
  %--------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
 %----------------------------------------------
 \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
 \begin{document}
      %----------------------------------------------
\mbox{}\begin{figure*}[b]
 \scriptsize\bfseries
 \leavevmode\rlap{
 \Longstack{
  Republic of...\\ 
  Ministry of Higher Education, Scientific Research\\
  and Information and Communication\\
  Technologies\\
  \\
  ... University\\
  National Engineering School of ... }}\hfill%
 \includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{example-image}\hfill%
 \llap{\Longstack{
   Computer Engineering \& Applied Mathematics\\
   Department\\
   \\
   \\
   ST-EN07/00\\
   \textsc{Graduation Project}\\
   Serial N: 2015 / DIMA-033
 }}

 \stackunder[1pt]{\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
            {\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
\end{figure*}
%----------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I want to make it in the head of the page and not in the bottom. What I should do?

Comment: @Student Change `\begin{figure*}[b]` to `\begin{figure*}[t]`.  Also, if you are having other text on the page, you don't need the `\mbox{}`.  That is there just to put *something* on the page with the figure.